# Read calendar data in Android application

Tags: android, android-calendar

I need to show a list view which will show the details of the calendar which is already created through an android application. i.e. it will show the title, timings, event locations etc reading from calendar.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you mean your app wants to read the data created by another application?

Comment: Step #1: Come up with a list of all calendar applications for Android. There are probably thousands of these. Step #2: For each, contact the developer and ask them if they have an API.